# Unprotect selective Azure function from azure Azure AD

Tags: azure, function

Just want to check if there is a way to unprotect certain Azure Function from Azure AD?
My use case to get information from azure function (e.g environment)and display at the login page. Hence the user is not login, so I can’t call any protected Azure function.

Is there possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a HTTP Triggered functions you can specify the level of authority one needs to have in order to execute it.

```
[FunctionName("Anonymous")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    ILogger logger)
{
    // your code
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks your reply. based on the documentation, AuthLevel is referring to the Keys created not so much of make a azure function to be unprotected by Azure Active Directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#configuration

AuthLevel   Determines what keys, if any, need to be present on the request in order to invoke the function. The authorization level can be one of the following values:

anonymous—No API key is required.
function—A function-specific API key is required. This is the default value if none is provided.

admin—The master key is required.
For more information, see the section about authorization keys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#authorization-keys